# Picking file names out of a website to download in powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell-2.0

Problem: I'm working on making a PowerShell script that will download the sites source code, find all the file targets, and then download said targets. I'm alright for authentication for the moment, so on my test website, I enabled anonymous authentication, enabled directory browsing, and disabled all other default pages, so all I get is a list of files on my site. What I have so far is this:

```
$source = "http://testsite/testfolder/"
$webclient = New-Object system.net.webclient
$destination = "c:/users/administrator/desktop/test/"
$webclient.downloadstring($source)
```

The `$webclient.downloadstring` will return basically the source code of my site, and I can see the files I want wrapped in the rest of the code. My question to you guys is what is the best and/or easiest ways of isolating the links I want so I can do a foreach command to download all of them?

Also, for extra credit, how would I go about adding in code to download folders and the files within those folders from my site?  I can at least make seperate scripts to pull the files from each subfolder, but obviously it would be much nicer to get it all in one script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on PowerShell v3 the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet may be of help.

To get an object representing the website:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=powershell"
```

To get all the links in that website:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=powershell" | select -ExpandProperty Links
```

And to just get a list of the `href` elements:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=powershell" | select -ExpandProperty Links | select href
```

If you are on PowerShell v2 or earlier you'll have to create an `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object and use that to navigate the page:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
# sleep for a second while IE launches
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
$ie.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=powershell")
# sleep for a second while IE opens the page
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
$ie.Document.Links | select IHTMLAnchorElement_href
# quit IE
$ie.Application.Quit()
```

Thanks to [this blog post](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/new-in-powershell-3-parse-html-without-ie-object-unless-a-local-file/) where I learnt about `Invoke-WebRequest`.

**Update**:
One could also download the website source like you posted and then extract the links from the source. Something like this:

```
$webclient.downloadstring($source) -split "<a\s+" | %{ [void]($_ -match "^href=[`'`"]([^`'`">\s]*)"); $matches[1] }
```

The `-split` part splits the source along lines that start with `<a` followed by one or more spaces. The output is placed in an array which I then pipe through a `foreach-object` block. Here I match each line on the regexp which extracts the links part and outputs it.

If you want to do more with the output you can pipe it further through another block which does something with it.

Comment: Rakhesh, I appreciate the quick response and help. Im limited to PowerShell 2.0, so I tried using the InternetExplorer.Application stuff you posted. When I got to the '$ie.Document.Links | select IHTMLAnchorElement_href' part, I would get a return of:
'IHTMLAnchorElement_href
-----------------------

'
Should I be seeing my links below the lines? My ultimate goal is to be able to do some kind of foreach command or something in order to invoke BITS or a webclient.downloadfile command to pull the files over to my local system. If anyone can help, Id be grateful.

Comment: Yup, I get a list of links when I try the code above. Are you trying it with you local site or something else (like SO, for instance)?

Comment: Im not using a local site; I'm connecting to another computer running IIS (Windows 7 OS). Like I said before, I enabled directory browsing, and disabled the default documents, so all I get is a page with links to my files and folders (which is what I want). I need to download every file and folder on my website. I can get the source code over to my client laptop, but my knowledge in PowerShell is not great, so I do not know how to pull the filenames from the source code and throw those into some code to download each of them.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working. I've updated my answer with another way - using regexps to extract the links - does that work for you?

Comment: Holy crap, thats a lot of meta characters. That said, it looks like that worked like a champ! Thank you very much for helping me out!