# Download a series of files with changing names via HTTP in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script to download a series of files from a http location to a local directory.  The filename consists of a time and date stamp as well as a static string.  As far as I know, I have to have the exact filename when downloading using System.Net.Webclient, which is where I have an issue.

Is there either a wildcard method to use in System.Net.Webclient, or is there a way I can capture and parse the directory listing as it appears when I go to the parent directory in a browser?

The filenames are as such...

```
FLASH_20131112_203721_WEEKLYFY_C.dat.gz
```

The first numerical portion is a date, the second portion is a timestamp.

Comment: I saw both of those and from what I can gather, neither will work for me.  In the parsing cases they have a file to download and parse.  In my case there is no file that has a list of the current files. I can get a list by browsing to the directory itself and Apache or IIS generates a list that I can see.  Is there some way I can get the contents of this list into powershell?  If there is I haven't found it.

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/a/19489144/2610230? In the Updated bit I give a regex that will pull out the links in the directory listing. If that works for you maybe you can modify the regexp to match your filename pattern.