# Error in foreach that it cannot index into a null array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Following an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487005/picking-file-names-out-of-a-website-to-download-in-powershell). I am doing the following:

```
param(
    # Required. Download source location (website).
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [URI] $URL
)
process
{
     $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
     $fileItems = $wc.downloadstring($URL) -split "<a\s+" | %{ [void]($_ -match "^HREF=[`'`"]  ([^`'`">\s]*)"); $matches[1] };
     return $fileItems;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ForEach-Object : Cannot index into a null array.
At J:\LMIData\PowerShell\HTTP_based_downloader.ps1:9 char:61
+     $fileItems = $wc.downloadstring($URL) -split "<a\s+" | % <<<< { [void]($_ -match "^HREF=[`'`"]([^`'`">\s]*)"); $matches[1]; };
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1:Int32) [ForEach-Object], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

The "char:61" location is right after the `%`.

Now, what is interesting is that this code worked previously. Is this possibly an issue in the `-match` regex? I have not declared the `$matches` array - could that be it?

I am at a loss here as I am still new to powershell. I am aware that I can get the list of links in powershell v3+ using `Invoke-WebRequest` but that is not an option as the system this is running on is locked at v2 for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

Looks more like your download might not be what you expected.
Try adding some debug.

```
param(
    # Required. Download source location (website).
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [URI] $URL
  )
  process
  {
     $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
     $Download = $wc.downloadstring($URL)
     Write-Debug "Download is $Download"
     $fileItems = $Download -split "<a\s+" | %{ [void]($_ -match "^HREF=[`'`"]  ([^`'`">\s]*)"); $matches[1] };
     return $fileItems;
  }
```

and set your $DebugPreference to 'Continue' amd see what your d/l payload looks like.

Comment: As I said. I am a newbie to PS. What is `$DebugPreference`

Comment: If I just return `$Download` or if I return just `$Download -split "<a\s+"` I have the expected output.

Comment: What happens if you return the split and run it through that match?

Comment: Same error. It has just moved to the line where I try and do the match. If I initialize the `$match` like '$match = @()` I no longer get the error but I do not get an array either.

Comment: Then your regex isn't capturing anything.

Comment: Found this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee835717.aspx. It states that the `$match[]` array is created by PS when it uses `-match`. So, fun stuff.

Comment: Yep.  You'll need to debug that regex.

Comment: Interestingly the issue was that one item on the page had 0 length. So, a dead href item. Added filter to check for that and now no bombs!